# Directive to count nested arrays in Angular 14 when is used the component multiple times

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have this simple directive in Angular for counting nested arrays:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rhsNestedArrayCounter]',
  exportAs: 'rhsNestedArrayCounter'
})
export class NestedArrayCounterDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {
  static nextIndex = -1;

  @Input() appCounter: number | string = '';

  index;

  constructor() {
    this.index = NestedArrayCounterDirective.nextIndex++;
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (typeof this.appCounter === 'string') {
      return;
    }
    NestedArrayCounterDirective.nextIndex = this.appCounter;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    NestedArrayCounterDirective.nextIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

And I used it in my html like this, lets call it FormComponent:

```
<form [formGroup]="detailForm" class="form-container">
  <ng-container rhsNestedArrayCounter="0">
    <div *ngFor="let section of sections; let sectionIndex = index">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="section-content">
          <h3>{{ section.title }}</h3>
          <div formArrayName="responses">
            <div
              *ngFor="
                let questionWithAnswer of section.questionsWithAnswers;
                let questionIndex = index
              ">
              <div class="question">
                <div
                  rhsNestedArrayCounter
                  #counter="rhsNestedArrayCounter"
                  class="question-content"
                  [formGroupName]="counter.index">
                  <h4>
                    {{
                      questionWithAnswer.questionDescription
                        | textReplacer: '#EmployeeName':employeeName
                    }}
                  </h4>
                  <div>
                    <mat-form-field
                      color="accent"
                      id="sectionAnswer-{{ counter.index }}">
                      <textarea
                        matInput
                        placeholder="Answer"
                        formControlName="text"
                        name="text"
                        id="sectionAnswerInput-{{ counter.index }}"
                        [required]="questionWithAnswer.isRequired"
                        cdkTextareaAutosize
                        #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                        cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
                        cdkAutosizeMaxRows="6"></textarea>
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="responses.controls[counter.index].get('text')?.errors?.['required']"
                        id="sectionAnswerError"
                        >Required field</mat-error
                      >
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="responses.controls[counter.index].get('text')?.errors?.['minlength']"
                        id="sectionAnswerMinLengthError"
                        >Min 2 characters</mat-error
                      >
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="responses.controls[counter.index].get('text')?.errors?.['maxlength']"
                        id="sectionAnswerMaxLengthError"
                        >Max 6000 characters</mat-error
                      >
                      <mat-error
                        *ngIf="responses.controls[counter.index].get('text')?.errors?.['pattern']"
                        id="sectionAnswerSpecialCharactersPatternError"
                        >Only letters, numbers, and some punctuation marks are
                        allowed.</mat-error
                      >
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

When I used FormComponent in my PageComponent one time everything worked fine, now I have a PageTwoComponent and I need to use the FormComponent more than one time, and because this counter is global I got errors about the index. For example the form have 15 questions, and I got the error of index 16 because when start count the second FormComponent it start from 16 because the first FormComponent finish in 15 (using two times the FormComponent in a Parent component).

[image]

So I thought maybe used a dictionary in the directive where I have for every component a unique index for every name, but I don't know how to implement this, or maybe another idea (I'm a C# developer) any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want such usage `rhsNestedArrayCounter="0"` to   restore counter to index 0, and then just `rhsNestedArrayCounter` to save current index and increment it.

If that is so then you should firstly use ngOnInit hook rather than ngAfterViewInit, and, considering your usage `rhsNestedArrayCounter="0"` 0 would be passed as a string "0" here.

```
let counterValue = -1; // would work almost the same as the static prop
class NestedArrayCounterDirective  {
  @Input() rhsNestedArrayCounter: number | string = ''; // name of the input matters.
  index: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.rhs) {
     counterValue = +this.rhs;
    } else {
      this.index = counterValue++;
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy() { counterValue = -1;}
}
```

also to not make hacks with initializing and clearing the "counter" in directives, you can use a simple service for that counter, which you'll just put in the parent component's `providers` section

```
@Injectable()
class CounterService {
  private val = 0;  
  public getAndIncrement() {return this.val++;}
}
```

and that service should basically created "scoped" version of counter for the FormComponent and it should resolve the problem for you

provide service like here

```
@Component({providers: [CounterService],...}) cass FormComponent {}
```

and use increment in the directive like here

```
class NestedArrayCounterDirective {
  index = inject(CounerService).getAndIncrement();
}
```

even without any hooks it should work correctly

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't quite understand how this change manages the use of using the same component several times with the directive in a parent component?

Comment: you provide CounterService in the FormComponent providers- this way there will be a separate counter for every instance of FormComponent

Comment: I was testing the code for changing the directive that you gave me, doing the test with 2 divs and the for, it works well, but when I transfer it to the form so that it generates the questions dynamically, I start to have errors, for example, there are 15 questions It only renders the first 3 but when I click on the input of the third the 4th and the 5th question start to appear, I click on the 5th input and more appear... but I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: Another question, I understand the idea of the service, but I don't fully understand how to use it inside of the FormComponent for counting?

Comment: `@Component({providers: CounterService,...}) cass FormComponent` this would make sure that there will be a service instance created for each FormComponent. `counterService = inject(CounerService); ... this.index = this.counterService.getAndIncrement();` in the directives. and you won't need the initializer use of the directive

Comment: Andrei!!, I changed it to use only the service as you commented, and it worked as you said, if you create or update the answer with only the part of the service I use it as the answer! Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: @MarcoNuñez updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

using the directive multiple times in different components, they all share the same static nextIndex value, which is causing the index to increment globally.

create a counter service

```
// counter.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CounterService {
  private counters: { [key: string]: number } = {};

  getCounter(key: string): number {
    if (!this.counters[key]) {
      this.counters[key] = -1;
    }
    return ++this.counters[key];
  }

  resetCounter(key: string): void {
    this.counters[key] = -1;
  }
}
```

user the counert in your directive

```
import { CounterService } from './path-to-counter.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rhsNestedArrayCounter]',
  exportAs: 'rhsNestedArrayCounter'
})
export class NestedArrayCounterDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {
  @Input() appCounter: number | string = '';
  @Input() counterKey: string = 'default';

  index: number;

  constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {
    this.index = this.counterService.getCounter(this.counterKey);
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (typeof this.appCounter === 'string') {
      return;
    }
    this.counterService.resetCounter(this.counterKey);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.counterService.resetCounter(this.counterKey);
  }
}
```

send unique key for every instance

```
<ng-container rhsNestedArrayCounter="0" counterKey="formOne">
  <!-- ... -->
</ng-container>

<ng-container rhsNestedArrayCounter="0" counterKey="formTwo">
  <!-- ... -->
</ng-container>
```